# Necessity of building a cross compiler

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, x86, osdev

I am using a 64 bit linux machine
I was doing some operating system development, where it is said that you need to use a cross compiler to generate code for the target system.
The barebones tutorial (https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_bones) instructs one to build a i686-gcc compiler using the native compiler of the host operating system (I believe that it is gcc 7.4.0).

However, one can generate code for other target platforms using gcc itself, eg.

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c -fno-pie -m32 source.c -o source.o        
ld source.o -o flatbinary.bin -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x10000 --oformat binary
```

I believe that the first command creates an ELF object for a 32 bit machine. (Using no standard library? I think that -ffreestanding stands for that)
The second command creates a flat binary image where the absolute (virtual?) addresses are offset by 0x10000.

Isn't this what a cross compiler does? Why do I need a separate cross compiler??

Note: I have just ventured into this vast world of compilers, object files, etc. and am just beginning to get an understanding. I might have some concepts fundamentally incorrect. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x86-64 ELF GCC (like you'll find on Linux) is perfectly capable of compiling for 32-bit x86/ELF.

If you were on some other ISA, like ARM, you would need a cross compiler to target i386.

If you were on Windows, you might need a cross-compiler to make 32-bit x86 ELF objects because MinGW or Cygwin GCC would be making PE/COFF object files, not ELF.  Right machine code, wrong object-file format.

Comment: How can you know what format and what ABI OPs OS will use to write that is not needed?

Comment: @PeterCordes I've read that a cross compiler helps not repeatedly including stuff like -nostdlib or such options.... What does this mean?? I'm relatively new to this and all this is pretty confusing... obviously owing due to the immense complexity of multiple ISAs, operating systems, etc. that are used nowadays :(

Comment: @P__J__: you can tell by reading the tutorial and seeing that it's for making an i686-elf kernel.  If you already have a compiler that can target that ISA / object file format, you're all set.

Comment: @SuraajKS: You're not linking with your compiler anyway, you're using `ld` directly.  `gcc -nostdlib` is like using `ld` without adding CRT start files or `-lc` like the compiler normally does.  (Run `gcc -v hello.c` to see what it normally links in when compiling a normal executable.)  Since library functions won't be available (unless your kernel provides its own implementation of them) you have to be careful how you write your code...

Comment: @PeterCordes What is the difference between using a compiler to link and using a linker to link? We're usually taught that a compiler produces object files from c source code... So does it implicitly call a linker?

Comment: @SuraajKS The program `gcc` isn't really the compiler itself, it's front-end program that invokes the actual compiler and (by default) the linker. Also `gcc` could add some specific libraries when it invokes the linker, for example GCC-specific libraries for built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to build a cross-compiler to avoid mistakes while compiling the operating system but it's not necessary.